# Pymysql can not link to the mysql

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

[image]

[image: here is mysql]

ps:I work in win7 virtualbox system,and I blocked the virtual network card,is that reason it?

Comment: I suggest avoid posting passwords in QA websites and forums. In case of posting a screenshot, making the passwords blurry might be a good idea. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a Unix socket (hence the AF_UNIX in the error) to connect to MySQL, where it's not available on the platform (Windows). I suggest using a TCP connection instead.

Remove the `unix_socket` argument to `pymysql.connect` call, and replace it with `port=3306`.
So the connection line will be like this:

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='root', passwd='something', db='mysql')
```

Also make sure MySQL server accepts network connections as well. This can be set on MySQL server configurations.
If MySQL server is running on the same host where you're writing the client, then it should be fine. Otherwise you might need to allow connection from clients on other hosts to MySQL server.